# ( in -by-with) tradition , children play tricks on 1st april?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, prepositions

What is the correct prepostion accompanied with tradition , it means here traditionally or usually the children play tricks , so what is the correct , I think that the popular form is by tradition ?

Comment: [April 1st: correction] 1 April is not good here.

Comment: @Lambie: What's wrong with 1 April? Plenty of [credible](https://www.ons.gov.uk/peoplepopulationandcommunity/healthandsocialcare/conditionsanddiseases/bulletins/prevalenceofongoingsymptomsfollowingcoronaviruscovid19infectionintheuk/1april2021) [sources](http://news.bbc.co.uk/onthisday/hi/dates/stories/april/1/default.stm) use it... there's more than one correct way to write a date.

Comment: April Fools Day on April, the 1st

Comment: What sources did you check before asking here? Many online dictionaries provide you with examples in a phrase if you search for "tradition"

Comment: April Fool's day is April 1st or April first. 1 April sounds like a British style date, used in docs or letters. So it sounds odd as a statement. The cabinet reshuffle was 1 April. [ok]

Comment: Did you use Google? You should have.

Comment: Juliana and what is your trouble

Comment: According to tradition, by tradition, traditionally. 1 April would be spoken as 'the first of April'. Also, it's not just children who play April Fool tricks - see the notorious [spaghetti harvest hoax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti-tree_hoax)!

Comment: Why do you want to phrase it as "[something] tradition..." when you could just say, "Traditionally, children play tricks..."?

Comment: @Lambie: "sounds like a British style date" - well, that's what we use in Britain! Not just in documents and letters. Not really sure why you think there's anything wrong with it...

Comment: @psmears I know, I know. But in writing about April Fool's day you would not use it. would you? I have nothing against it per se. Think about how you would say it versus write it.

Comment: @Lambie: Personally at the start of a sentence I'd probably write it out in words, "The first of April", but it is commonly written as "1 April" or "25 December", even at the start of a sentence, and isn't remarkable - even if it might sound strange in other parts of the world :)